# Protractor - Create Sanity test that includes login

Tags: authentication, protractor, pageobjects, e2e-testing

I'm creating automated tests in Protractor for our site.
you have to login first in order to do anything on the site.
my problem is that for specific test (spec) - I can (have) to add 'login' - currently located in Page Object page. 
the problem is that when creating a sanity test that uses multiple tests (using 'Suite') - I currently have to login for every specific test and then logout at the end so the next test will work properly (since it login at first).
what is the right way to do it?
on one hand I want that every test will work on its own (login at first) - but on the other hand - when using it in sanity test- I want to login and logout only once during the sanity test.

this is the suite part from the conf.js file:

```
suites:{
    sanity: ['*/AccountSettingsTest.js','*/createApptest.js','*/openSourcePageTest.js','*/whatsNewTest.js']

},

specs: ['*/AccountSettingsTest.js'],
```

This is how I currently use the login:

```
var LoginPage = require('../global/LoginPage');
...
var login = new LoginPage();
...
login.clickLogin();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no `beforeSuite()` and `afterSuite()` if this is what you are asking about.

One thing that might work for you is to put the "logging in" part into `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.get("myurl");
    return loginPage.login(username, password);  // login may also return a promise
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. that's a nice idea. after some thoughts I decided that at the start of each spec I will check if I am logged in or not, and if not - I am logging in. BTW - I've found out that there is 'beforeAll' and 'afterAll' in Jasmine 2.0.

Comment: @user2880391 yeah, I decided not to elaborate about `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` because this works inside `describe` only. Note that for jasmine 1 there is `jasmine-beforeAll` third-party package. Thanks for the update.